# Start a script from bash in a loop, where each call only occurs when the former process is finished

Tags: python, bash, loops

Lets say i have a python script that takes multiple arguments as flags and i want to start this script multiple times with different arguments, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg1 in 1 2 3;
do
for arg2 in a b c;
do

python script.py -a1 $arg1 -a2 $arg2

done
done
```

Is it possible that the calls are getting called strictly after another? In other words, that each call waits for the last one to finish before it starts?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Of course it's possible. When you type command into an interactive shell, doesn't it wait for it to finish before you get the next command prompt?

Comment: Your example code is a good start, but learn to build easy tests to help you understand how shell processing works. Instead of `python script...` use `echo -a1 $arg1 -a2 $arg2; sleep 5;`  where the `sleep 5` is a quick running program that will help you see what is happening. Good luck.]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how bash works.  If you want them all to run in parallel, add `&` at the end of the `python` command.

```
python script.py -a1 $arg1 -a2 $arg2 &
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When we assume that one call of script.py last for 1 hour, will the next iteration of loop wait 1 hour until the last script call is finished?

Comment: @Gojih Yes, unless `script.py` puts _itself_ in the background and exits the started process before the background process has finished.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  If you use the `&`, then all 9 scripts will be started at once and will run in parallel.